# Refactor part of code in a new function, LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

I need refactor this code.

I need put the validation code in a new function and use that function in another functions.
This code

```
public function comprobarValidacion(\Request $request)
        {
             $validador =  $this->validator($request::all());
               $errors = $validador->errors()->all();

           if(count($errors)):

             return Redirect()->back()->withErrors($validador);

            endif;
        }
```

I try call it in each function like this

```
public function postLogin(\Request $request)
{

     $this->comprobarValidacion($request::all());
     return Redirect()->back();
}
```

but it doesn´t works. the code, however if I put the comprobarValidacion content inside the any function works

This is the complete code;

.

```
class AuthController extends Controller {


            use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

            protected $auth;

             protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

             //despues de loguear

             protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/paginaporcrear';


            public function __construct(Guard $auth)
            {
              //  $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
              //  $this->middleware($auth);

                $this->auth = $auth;


            }


            protected function validator(array $data)
            {

                $reglas =  [
                    'name' => 'required|max:255',
                    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
                    'password' => 'required|min:1|confirmed',
                          ];
                $mensajes =    [
                    'required' => 'El campo :attribute es requerido',
                    'email' => 'El campo :atribute tiene que tener formato de email',
                            ];

                return  Validator::make($data, $reglas, $mensajes);
            }


            public function comprobarValidacion(\Request $request)
            {
                 $validador =  $this->validator($request::all());
                   $errors = $validador->errors()->all();

               if(count($errors)):

                 return Redirect()->back()->withErrors($validador);

                endif;
            }


            public function getRegistro()
            {
                return view('auth.register');
            }


            public function postRegistro(\Request $request)
            {
                    $validador =  $this->validator($request::all());

                   $errors = $validador->errors()->all();

                   if(count($errors)>0):

                     return Redirect()->back()->withErrors($validador);

                    endif;


                $this->create($request::all());



                \Session::flash('creado','El usuario '.$request::get('name').' ha sido creado exitosamente');
                return Redirect()->back();

            }

            public function getLogin()
            {

                return view('auth.login');
            }

            public function postLogin(\Request $request)
            {
                     // $validador =  $this->validator($request::all());
                     // $errors = $validador->errors()->all();

                     //   if(count($errors)):

                     //     return Redirect()->back()->withErrors($validador);

                     //    endif;


                 $this->comprobarValidacion($request::all());
                 return Redirect()->back();
            } }
```

¿How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you do the return in the comprobarValidacion function you are returning the result to the action. I would take a look at how the registration area does it in laravel (Auth/RegisterController)

It returns the validator then you run the ->validate method in the controller action. Laravel handles a failed call to validate() in the action automatically and calls convertValidationExceptionToResponse in the Exceptions Handler

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    // Notice how it doesn't call ->validate()
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name'     => 'required|max:255',
        'email'    => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

---

Then in the register action

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    // This runs the validate method in the action.
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create rules

```
public function add_user_rules(array $data)
{
  $messages = [
    'email.required' => 'Please enter email.'
  ];

  $validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => 'required|max:30|unique:email',
    'name' => 'required'
  ], $messages);

  return $validator;
}


public function postAdd(Request $request)
{
  $request_data = $request->all();
  $validator = $this->add_user_rules($request_data);
  if($validator->fails())
  {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
  }
  else
  {  
    //add 
  }       
}
```